# Save output of bash command into variable inside if..else statement

Tags: python, linux, variables, command, output

I have following function:

```
def check_process_running(pid_name):
    if subprocess.call(["pgrep", pid_name]):
        print pid_name + " is not running"
    else:
        print pid_name + " is running and has PID=" 

check_process_running(sys.argv[1])
```

if I run the script it gives me:

```
$ ./test.py firefox
22977
firefox is running and has PID=
```

I need to get pid_num to work with the process further. I've learnt that if I want to create variable with above pid of value 22977 I can use:

```
tempvar = subprocess.Popen(['pgrep', sys.argv[1]], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
pid_num = tempvar.stdout.read()
print pid_num
22977
```

Is there solution where construction of tempvar is not needed, where the pid is picked up and saved into variable pid_num within the if..else statement as it is in my function? Or what is the most straight forward way to create the pid_num variable with just one call into the shell using subprocess and keep the function as simple as it is now?

EDIT:

With bellow solution I was able to reconstruct the statement, keep it simple and have pid_num to work with the process further:

```
def check_process_running(pid_name):
    pid_num = subprocess.Popen(['pgrep', sys.argv[1]], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).communicate()[0]
    if pid_num:    
        print pid_name + " is running and has PID=" + pid_num
    else:
        print pid_name + " is not running"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pid_number = subprocess.Popen(['pgrep', sys.argv[1]], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).communicate()[0]
```

maybe? or probably better

```
pid_number = subprocess.check_output(['pgrep', sys.argv[1]])
```